# Organizing API-Calls in callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, design-patterns, architecture, refactoring

We are maintaining several Rails-Apps which all pose a similar problem that we don't have a really good solution to: All these apps contain models that need to make a API-Call to an external service in their lifecycle.

Possible cases:

- User is subscribed to a Newsletter-subscriber-list, when successfully created
- Prices for an offer are synced with an external shopping-system after updating
- Product is updated in the Search-Index after updating

What we exprienced to **NOT** be a good solution: Adding these calls to the `after_*`callbacks of the model. Since that breaks tests fast, cause all factories now have to deal with the api-calls.

**I'm looking for a good way to organize these API-call. How do you guys do this?**

Ideas we came up with, which I considered not real ideal:

- Moving those callbacks to the controller. Now they get easily forgotten, when creating an object
- Spawning an asynchronous worker to handle the api-call. Then every - even small app - needs to have the overhead of a delayed job-queue, like sidekiq.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are concerned about testing you could [put the callback methods into a separate class](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#callback-classes) and mock the callback class during testing. Here's an example using RSpec, given the following `Foo` and `FooCallbacks` classes:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save FooCallbacks
end

class FooCallbacks
  def self.after_save
    fail "Call to external API"
  end
end
```

You can write and successfully run a spec like this:

```
describe Foo do

  before do
    allow(FooCallbacks).to receive(:after_save)
  end

  it "should not invoke real APIs" do
    Foo.create
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I now did it, after the advise:

In `Foo`:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save Foo::DataSync
end
```

`Foo:DataSync`looks like this:

```
class Foo::DataSync
  def self.before_save(foo)
     ...do the API-Calls...
  end
end
```

Now for testing in  rspec I added this:

To `spec_helper.rb`:

```
config.before(:each) do
  Foo::DataSync.stub(:before_save)
end
```

Note that `config.before(:suite)` will not work, since `Foo:DataSync` is not loaded at that time.

Now `foo_spec.rb` contains just this:

```
describe Foo do
  let(:foo) {create(:foo)}

  it "will sync its data before every save" do
    expect(Foo::DataSync).to receive(:before_save).with(foo)

    foo.save
  end
end
```

The `Foo::DataSync` can be tested like this:

```
describe Foo::DataSync do
  let!(:foo) {create(:foo)}

  before do
    Foo::DataSync.unstub(:before_save)
  end

  after do
    Foo::DataSync.stub(:before_save)
  end

  describe "#before_save" do
    ...my examples...
  end
end
```